# Ansible variable list span

Tags: variables, ansible, ovirt

When adding a variable list in Ansible how would one achieve a span of similar values? For instance "000-100" - in an Ansible hosts file this can be done by listing like so, "hostname-[a:v].com". Would this process be the similar in a variable list?

My use case is to provision many VM's within oVirt in a single go without having to make a line by line list.

```
---
- name: Create VM based on template
  hosts: ovirt-engine
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  vars:
  - temp: '{{temp_fedora25}}'
  - iname:
      - db-aa
      - db-ab
      - db-ac

  tasks:

    - name: Giving Birth to lil Baby VM's
      ovirt:
          user: '{{ovirt_usr}}'
          password: '{{ovirt_pass}}'
          url: '{{engine_url}}'
          instance_name: "{{item}}"
          instance_nic: ovirtmgmt
          resource_type: template
          image: '{{temp}}'
          zone: superblade-a
          disk_alloc: preallocated
      with_items: "{{iname}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sequence](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-integer-sequences) lookup:

```
- name: numeric
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_sequence: start=1 count=10 format=server-%0d


- name: characters from small 'a'
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_sequence: start=0x61 count=10 format=server-%c

- name: save for future use
  set_fact:
    my_seq: "{{ lookup('sequence','start={} count={} format={}{}'.format(beg,cnt,pref,fmt),wantlist=True) }}"
  vars:
    beg: 1
    cnt: 10
    pref: host-
    fmt: '%0d'
```

You can skip `set_fact` and define `my_seq` in vars section, but if you use `my_seq` much, list generation will be done internally every time. With `set_fact` list is generated once.

Comment: Yep, right there in the docs...works well, with some tweaking for my case of course. I am wondering if these values can be reused as registered varibles? Im adding another answer with my full solution just to be thorough.

Comment: added example with `set_fact`.

Comment: Super...does the trick.I'll have to scale up my playbook(s) to test passing those variables around.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the correct answer from Konstantin, I'm adding the full solution as per my case....

My goal is to be able to reuse the sequenced values as registered variables in order to pass the instance name to host name. This works so far but Im sure it can be streamlined by nesting variables perhaps?

```
---
- name: Create VM based on template
  hosts: ovirt-engine
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  vars:
  - temp: '{{temp_fedora25}}'
  - host_pre: db
  - host_seq: a%c
  - host_cnt: 3
  - host_srt: 0x61

  tasks:

    - name: Giving Birth to lil Baby VM's
      ovirt:
         user: '{{ovirt_usr}}'
         password: '{{ovirt_pass}}'
         url: '{{engine_url}}'
         instance_name: "{{item}}"
         instance_nic: ovirtmgmt
         resource_type: template
         image: '{{temp}}'
         zone: superblade-a
         disk_alloc: preallocated
      with_sequence: start="{{host_srt}}" count="{{host_cnt}}" format="{{host_pre}}-{{host_seq}}"
```